# DATEVALUE not accepting one type of arguments as per MS office documentation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was trying various date strings combinations which can be converted to proper date in our programs. Out of 7 types of strings, I am getting correct output in six cases. However in one case which is being supported by Microsoft Documentation is giving type mismatch error. [MS Office Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) and the relevant portion is :

> `=DATEVALUE(A2 & "/" & A3 & "/" & A4)`
>
> Serial number of a date created by combining the values in cells A2,
>   A3, and A4.
>
> 40850

Various strings combinations and result sheet snapshot is appended here.

[image: DATAVALUE_1][image: DATAVALUE_2]

I have entered 14,12,2018 in `G8`,`G9` and `G10` cells respectively but `DATAVALUE`gives Runtime error 13 on formula `= DateValue(G8 & "/" & G9 & "/" & G10)`.

I have formatted `G8:G10`in Text Format. My Excel Version is 2016 and Short Date as per system is in `15-01-2019` format.

Please help me in resolving this issue as I wish to incorporate date from worksheet cells in many cases.
If someone likes to view the excel related file, it is uploaded to dropbox as per link [Networkdays exercise.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzwac2641uad2pw/WORKDAY%20%26%20networkdays%20exercise.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: The reference you linked is for a formula used in a cell. Not for VBA. Also, VBA does not know what `G8` is (unless you declared a variable by that name). If you want to reference a cell that way in VBA you could use `Range("G8")`.

Comment: @hsan you are right. It works as per your suggestion. Please make it an answer so that I may tick it.